# [go/docker/podman]: fetch container image information without downloading the whole image

Tags: docker, go, podman

I am currently developing a small program that uses constraints to [check container image labels](https://github.com/volker-raschek/civ). The whole thing should run automatically in the CI.

I am currently using docker to get the labels of the images. However, I always have to download the container image. Now I wonder if there is a way to get the meta information without downloading the image with docker or alternatively podman.

If yes, I would be glad to get some sample code.

Comment: You could look at [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo), which is written in Go and does exactly what you are describing. You could of course also just refer to the [API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags). Also see https://hub.docker.com/support/doc/how-do-i-authenticate-with-the-v2-api.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools do this, including crane, skopeo, and my own regclient. The specs for this are defined in OCI. Specifically:

- config json which is stored as a blob, containing the labels: https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/config.md
- image manifest that contains the config descriptor: https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/manifest.md
- distribution spec that tells how to pull manifests and blobs: https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md

I'd recommend using a library for this, mainly to handle the authentication, which can be challenging. Or if you just want a quick CLI, here's the example with regctl from [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient):

```
regctl image config $image_name
```

The above also accepts Go templates in the `--format` flag, allowing you to retrieve specific labels. You can see the implementation for that, in Go, in that [command definition](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/blob/main/cmd/regctl/image.go#L223).
​